# Multi Tenant linking account after default tenant

Tags: firebase, multi-tenant, google-identity

We are transitioning to a multi tenant setup on firebase auth.  The issue is our default tenant already has the base accounts I need to link with since the uid is tied to all the records on our firestore.

When i create a new tenant it works but I cannot link since it is a different tenant than the original.  This means all the prior user records are orphaned on the firestore as they utilize the uid of the default tenant.

Anyway I can get the new tenant that is utilizing a Microsoft provider to link to the uid of the default tenant?

The only thing i can think of is go through every record and change the userid to the new tenant userid, but it is plagued with issues.

I tried using the linking code from
The firebase docs for multi tenant but the linking seems to only work if both account providers are on the same tenant

Again the Default project/tenant houses the correct userID.  I want the Microsoft tenant to use that uid, as that is the uid that all of the firebase collections are tied to.

```
loginMicrosoft() {
  const auth = getAuth();
  auth.tenantId = this.tenantId;

  const l = this.loader;
  provider.setCustomParameters({
    prompt: "consent",
    tenant: this.tenant
  });

  signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
    .then(async result => {
      const pendingcredential = OAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      var result2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
      const email = result2._tokenResponse.email;
      auth.tenantId = null;
      fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(auth, email).then(methods => {
        console.log(methods);
        if (methods[0] == "password") {
          signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, "Test12345!").then(
            cred => {
              console.log("WE ARE IN", cred.user);
              linkWithCredential(cred.user, pendingcredential)
                .then(linkResult => {
                  console.log("SUCCESSFUL LINK", linkResult);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log("ERROR WITH LINKING", err);
                });
            }
          );
        }
      });
    })}
```

Everything works except the Microsoft Tenant login has a completely different uid and the linkWithCredential simply throws an error saying invalid site id (I assume bc each auth is on a different tenantId.